# Why does the assumption that speed of light $c$ is constant exist?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, physical-constants

This is I'm sure a very basic and juvenile question. Why do we take the assumption that $c$ is constant in all situations to be a law? It does work out that it fits the standard model well but it has never been verified at a large distance. The Michelson-Morey experiment and it's replications over the years seem to prove that there is no aether. The most sensitive instruments don't seem to pick up any deviations from the derived constant. But can we be sure that the aether is not the cause of potential $c$ variations, even if the medium does not exist can we be sure there is not some other force acting upon $c$.

The experimental proofs seem to measure $c$ in a scale of alterations at very small distances and time, even with that precision it seems the possibility may exist that we do not see dilations at these small values. Those dilations would seem to be extremely, infinitesimally, small but it does not preclude the possibility.

This seems to leave the possibility that there exists a relationship we cannot accurately measure at the scale we are operating. Some force perhaps that only acts upon $c$ at larger scales. What makes me question is the cosmology findings that observed objects by JWST appear to be too large for the time frame that we believe the universe to exist. If we allow $c$ to be non constant and have variation over time it seems to be one potential reconciliation of these findings.

This is likely the reality of experimental physics, we can always have a doubt and question a 'law' based off the inaccuracy of our equipment at quantum scales. Until something definitively proves us wrong however we fit what we believe to be the facts.

Comment: As @mike says, the speed of light is currently constant by definition. So, if you seek to test the assumption that it's constant, you must come up with a nonstandard method of measuring either time or distance, and make a good case that your alternate method better captures the physics.

Comment: Occam's razor ... the assumption that the speed of light in vacuum is always $c$ (which is constant by definition) is the simplest assumption that fits the known facts.  If an empirical observation contradicted that assumption then we would have to find an alternative model.

Answer (score 4):

The quantity $c$ is a constant [by definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_light#Defined_as_an_explicit_constant)

Comment: There is content (beyond mere definition) to the assumption that $c$ is not infinite.

Answer (score 4):

A strong argument against "variable c" theories is that they directly imply energy nonconservation- something for which we have no experimental evidence.